# Spring integration Handle vs Transform

Tags: spring-integration, transform, handle

Can you explain me, why should I use transform method instead of handle with spring integration if bouth method can return new payload type?

For example

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow integerFlow() {
    return f -> f.handle(Integer.class, (p, h) -> p * 2);
}
```

and

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow integerFlow() {
    return f -> f.transform(Integer.class, p -> p * 2);
}
```

Whey do the same thing. I think so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are the same for your simple sample, but there are many other use-cases where it is better to prefer one over the other.

The first difference that transformer gives fully control when you return the whole `Message` instead of just `payload`. The transformer in the framework doesn't modify such a message and produce it to the output channel as is. At the same time the service activator modifies that message copying request headers. So, it is always need to keep in mind when you are going to return a `Message` from the transformer: you also need to carry request headers yourself. Otherwise you may lose some convenient headers like `replyChannel` or correlation details and a downstream logic won't work.

Another difference that transformer always requires some result value in return. The service activator is forgiving in this matter and for some reason you are free to return `null` to stop the flow.

To be honest I always say: transformer is a particular service activator implementation with its specific logic and requirements.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-transformation.html#messaging-transformation-chapter

Comment: Hi @Artem Bilan just hoping to get some clarification here (I just had the _exact_ same question as the individual who asked this, and found your answer here). It _sounds_ like you are saying that a Transformer leaves the **inbound** `Message` alone and instead produces a _different_ **outbound** `Message` that could have a totally different body + headers? And that with a Service Activator, the inbound and outbound `Messages` are the **same instances in memory**?

Comment: That's not correct. The message is an *immutable* object. You cannot change its properties: you only have to create a new message and probably copy headers from another one. Every replying `MessageHandler` produces a new message for reply even if you return the message object. The transformer does not do that. So, you indeed can reply just with the same input message, but what is the point of the transformer then if you don't transform the input message to something else. I guess it is better to ask a new SO question with much more context to answer you properly.

Comment: OK thanks @Artem Bilan, let me think about this and I may create a new question if I'm still unclear.